# NSIS exec JScript with parameters

Tags: nsis, wsh

I'm trying to run a JScript that receives a parameter (like a cmd argument).
Consider the following JScript:

**myScript.js:**

```
var args = WScript.Arguments; //get cmd args 
WScript.Echo(args[0]); //output the first argument gotten from NSIS
```

I'm trying to do so with the following NSIS script:

**installer.nsi:**

```
Var /GLOBAL argumentToSendForJScript
StrCpy argumentToSendForJScript "helloFromNSIS"
File 'runme.js'
Exec "wscript.exe C:\myScript.js $argumentToSendForJScript"
```

Problem is, the argument isn't arriving the JScript. I suspect that it is due to the fact the argument is arriving to `wscript.exe` instead of `myScript.js`, because it works if I execute the script directly from a windows command prompt instead of NSIS, like so:

```
myScript.js helloFromCMD
```

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: Why post incomplete code that does not even compile? (`StrCpy argumentToSendForJScript "helloFromNSIS"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WScript.Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84).aspx) is not a normal javascript array, you must access the items with `(123)`, not `[123]`.

```
Section
; Create a dummy script:
InitPluginsDir
FileOpen $0 "$PluginsDir\test.js" w
FileWrite $0 "var args = WScript.Arguments;$\n"
FileWrite $0 "WScript.Echo('length='+args.length, args(0));$\n"
FileClose $0

Var /GLOBAL argumentToSendForJScript
StrCpy $argumentToSendForJScript "helloFromNSIS"
ExecWait '"WScript.exe" "$PluginsDir\test.js" $argumentToSendForJScript'
SectionEnd
```